# "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2147023673/0x800704c7)

Tags: windows, jenkins, signtool

While using signtool for code signing on our buildserver jenkins shows the following error message:

```
Done Adding Additional Store
Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2147023673/0x800704c7)
SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
```

We use an EV code sign certificate on a USB token. All tools are the latest ones available actually.

Any ideas?

---

It is not a problem at all using the same build task and running it manually on the same machine (as the user mentioned below) that jenkins is running on, and the same environment / directory.

The Jenkins service runs on a Windows 10 pro VM as a simple user with admin rights (not as Local System).

For more details see this excerpt from the Jenkins log:

```
  Signiere FlinkySchule.FormularEditor.exe:
  Verbindung zu Token auf- bzw. abbauen
  ***** code signing *****
  Aktueller Pfad des signtool:
  c:\JW\FS\Production\Deployment\Tools\signtool\kits
  Zu signierende Datei:
  c:\JW\FS\Production\Application\Assemblies\FlinkySchule.FormularEditor\bin\Release\\FlinkySchule.FormularEditor.exe
  The following certificate was selected:
      Issued to: Dirk W.

      Issued by: GlobalSign CodeSigning CA - SHA256 - G3

      Expires:   Fri Apr 03 15:58:51 2020

      SHA1 hash: 4187Cxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyxyx7978C4


  Done Adding Additional Store
EXEC : error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (2147023673/0x800704c7) [c:\JW\FS\Production\Application\Assemblies\FlinkySchule.FormularEditor\FlinkySchule.FormularEditor.csproj]
EXEC : SignTool error : An unexpected internal error has occurred. [c:\JW\FS\Production\Application\Assemblies\FlinkySchule.FormularEditor\FlinkySchule.FormularEditor.csproj]
```

---

One issue was the over all path length:
Even in the year 2017 you will run into the 260 characters path length restriction. Annoying! But we solved this and the error still occurs sometimes.

Comment: Similarly I get this error when running signtool through a build script (not Jenkins) but it does not reproduce manually on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

**EV codesign with Jenkins using an eToken**

Found a solution using [jsign](https://ebourg.github.io/jsign/)

```
java -jar jsign-2.0.jar --keystore .\eToken.cfg --alias %yourCertAlias% --storetype PKCS11 --tsaurl http://rfc3161timestamp.globalsign.com/advanced --tsmode RFC3161 --storepass %tokenPassword% %file2sign%
```

eToken.cfg:

```
name=eToken
library=c:\WINDOWS\system32\eTPKCS11.dll
```

Get the certificates alias using java keytool

```
keytool -list -keystore NONE -storetype PKCS11 -providerclass sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 -providerArg eToken.cfg
```

This should output something like

```
Keystore-Typ: PKCS11
Keystore-Provider: SunPKCS11-eToken

Keystore enthält 1 Eintrag

te-318f471f-9a0e-4101-bf45-96a656cc2306, PrivateKeyEntry,
Zertifikat-Fingerprint (SHA1): 
41:87:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:X:XX:XX:XX:XX:79:78:C4
```

Maybe there are some more entries in the store. To find the right have look at your certifcate's fingerprint. The alias you need for jsign's alias parameter is the string in the example that starts with "te-318f4...."

Need more detailed help about this part? Please have a look at [Trustzone](https://www.trustzone.com/code-signing-java).

Please let me know if you are interested in knowing how we do an automated build process on a separate build machine using only one eToken USB device.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem as well. I was able to duplicate error outside of Jenkins by running Signtool.exe, but *when the prompt appeared for the token password, click cancel. You'll get the same error*.

I have a C program which watches for the Symantec prompt and automatically enters the toke password. But Jenkins clearly wasn't running Signtool.exe in the same context as my password helper program. So I then edited my program which runs Signtool.exe to run the password helper program as well. It was still no good. Then I realized that maybe the problem how Jenkins is being run on the node. I had the Jenkins node running a service. **Once I stopped the service, and connected by running the java command directly on the command line, it worked!**

So now I know, if I'm going to run signtool on a Windows node, make sure the node is connected by running on the command line (via scheduled task), not a service. This changes the context Jenkins is run under which allows SignTool and the Token Prompt to play nice.

Comment: Can you provide any details on how you got it to work as a scheduled task?  I am able to get this to work if I launch Jenkins via the browser. I still got prompted by the token software for the password, but it eventually build.  But I tried launching it via a Scheduled Task using the the java command (not the jnlp file) and was not prompted and got the same error.  Task runs as same account, with highest privileges, etc.

Comment: I just got it to work. I had the -workdir option when launching the jar and that didn't work. Removing that and using the 'start in' field to start in the workdir worked.  Instructions were [on the wiki here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Launch+Java+Web+Start+slave+agent+via+Windows+Scheduler)

Comment: We just had this. Our Bamboo agent that deals with it was logged in as the wrong user, so unlocking the key on the user it should have been running on obviously had no effect. Make sure your service runs the correct user.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it by installing the latest Windows 10 SDK, i.e. 10.0.15063.0

Comment: On my side, using latest SDK 10.0.16299.0 I still get this error. After this error occured, the token is "closed" and I need to trigger a manual sign to re-enter the password in the token dialog.

Comment: For me also the problem persisted after making sure I was using the latest. But I could imagine that for some very old signtool versions this could be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I omitted the countersignature :

```
 /tr http://tsa.starfieldtech.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to specify which certificate should be used for signing

```
/n "My Certificate Name"
```

Edit: Sorry my error code was different but google brought me here, so still might be helpful.
(-2146435071/0x80100001)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your CI machine is logged in as the correct user (the one you unlock the token with). For example, we use the SafeNet authentication client. We log in the token once after machine starts. Someone later re-installed the Bamboo agent that deals with our signing, but did not set the service to login with the correct user, so for that user, the token was not logged in.